# AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to use the load_img function from the keras.preprocessing.image module in my Python code to load an image, but I am getting the following error message:

AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img'

This is the code I am using:

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img'
```

This is the code I am using:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img(
    'dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_3.jpg', target_size=(64, 64))
```

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting this error and how I can fix it? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How about change your approach by using `tf.keras.utils.load_img(image_path)
`?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your help in solving my issue. I really appreciate it!